# Amount value in apex interactive grid

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am using the Interactive grid in APEX. I have entered the value in the first row 1000.00 and the value in the second row as 500. I want to get the total value 1,500.00 in an Hidden item and display.

I am able to get the value as 1,500  But the .00 is getting striped off.
How to achieve the result in javascript?

If I use parseFloat, .00 is getting removed.

var a = 0;
var t = 0;

```
    //a= parseFloat($v("value"));
    a= $v("value"); //row value in the loop   1000.00 in the first row and 500 in the second row
```

some Code....
t+= a;

return t;

If I don't use the parseFloat, the t value is getting concatenated(01,000,500) instead of adding. If I use parseFloat, .00 is getting stripped off(1,500). I want .00 only if the user entered the value like that.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`parseFloat` returns a floating-point number - when you then display the value, it must be converted to a string and by default this only includes significant digits - since `1500` is equal to `1500.00` it returns simply `1500`.

To show a fixed number of decimal digits, use `toFixed`, e.g. `a.toFixed(2)` will return `1500.00`.

If you want to match the precision based on the value entered by the user, you will need to determine the number of fractional digits by examining the value they originally entered. How you do this will probably involve getting the length of the original string after the decimal separator; how you handle the fact that you are aggregating over multiple values (with potentially differing numbers of fractional digits) you would need to work out.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey Kemp, Thanks for your inputs. I will work on that.